# Unity teletransportarme hacia donde este mirando

Tags: c#, unity

estoy haciendo un shooter pero con cosas random como la nueva arma de fortnite(agarratron) o habilidades de valorant(especificamente quiero el tp de omen), mi codigo no me esta funcionando pero no me da ningun error(cam y player si tienen asignados sus respectivos objetos)

```
public Camera cam;
public Transform player;

if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{
    RaycastHit hit;
    Ray ray = cam.ViewportPointToRay(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f));

    if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100))
    {
        player.transform.position = hit.transform.position; //este no funciona
        player.transform.position = hit.point + hit.normal * 2f; //este tampoco funciona
    }
}
```

intente hacer algunas combinaciones como cambiar position por localPosition, quitar .transform y que quede player.position(o player.localPosition), junto con eso cambiar entre las 2 funciones de teleportarse(hit.point... y hit.transform.position) y junto con eso cambiar public Transform player por public GameObject player, use todas esas combinaciones y nada, ni un error para ver que esta mal

de momento no quiero que solo funcione en lugares con una tag o layer especificos, quiero que funcione donde sea

Answer (score 1):

Tu código se ve mayormente bien, aunque parece que te faltan algunos componentes de tu MonoBehavior (Script).

A continuación, un ejemplo funcional de lo que tratas de hacer:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Teleport : MonoBehaviour {
    public Camera Cam;
    public Transform Player;

    void Update() {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Raycast(Cam.transform.position, Cam.transform.forward, out hit, 100)) {
                Player.transform.position = hit.point + (hit.normal * 2f);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

En este caso recomiendo que si solo tratas de lanzar un rayo del medio de la camara utilices la posición `Cam.transform.position` y dirección frontal `Cam.transform.forward` de la camara para el Raycast, te reduce la complejidad cognitiva del código (En todo caso tu uso de ViewportPointToRay se ve bien), también asegúrate que el `Player` sea la raíz de tu personaje, o sea el objeto más alto en la jerarquía para que muevas todos sus componentes y no solo una parte de este.

También ten en cuenta que `hit.normal` es la dirección normal de la superficie de colisión con la que choco el rayo, o sea que, si es una pared, la dirección normal ira en contra, tal vez querrías remplazar esto por `Vector3.up` que siempre apuntara hacia arriba en el mundo.

En caso de que tengas problemas en depurar código con Raycasts puedes utilizar la función `Debug.DrawLine`, por ejemplo, colocando lo siguiente dentro del if:

```
Debug.DrawLine(hit.point, hit.point + hit.normal);
```

Con esto podrás ver en la vista de escena en el editor una linea que representara la dirección normal del choque `hit.normal` partiendo desde donde choco el rayo `hit.point`, puedes cambiar el color con distintas versiones de la función si no se aprecia bien en la escena.

También como mencionas que quieres que funcione en todas las capas, la función `Physics.Raycast` tiene un overload que te permite especificar las capas con las que quieres que choque el rayo, puedes exponer una variable de tipo `LayerMask` en tu script y pasárselo a la función para asegurarte de que capas está utilizando.

También toma en cuenta la estructura de tu personaje, usualmente los personajes tienen un colisionador de capsula por lo que un Raycast de la camara puede chocar con este colisionador, ahí podrías utilizar las capas de colisión o simplemente mover el punto inicial del rayo usando `Cam.transform.forward` para que tenga una clase de compensación por el colisionador de tu personaje.

Comment: hola, el codigo "jugador.transform.position = hit.point + (Vector3.up * 2f);" funciona perfectamente, si apunto casi hasta arriba me teletransporta arriba de alguna figura, pero si apunto a una pared tambien hace lo mismo y queria bloquear eso, que solo me teletransporte a superficies asi y no a paredes, ni a rampas o pendientes, aqui esta un ejemplo https://imgur.com/a/DLq8fyS

Comment: @AlanRichter Podrías evitar superficies verticales usando el ángulo de `hit.normal` calculado con `Vector3.Angle`, puedes comparar `hit.normal` con `Vector3.up` y comparar los grados para saber si deberías de mover al jugador o no, para moverte sobre una superficie no visible (Arriba de una pared) se necesitaría de algo más elaborado.

Comment: la verdad no sabria como hacer todo eso mas elaborado pero gracias de todas formas